# Deleting a row in Accumulo using Pyaccumulo

Tags: python, thrift, accumulo

I'm trying to delete a row using the RowDeletingIterator.  I'm running Accumulo 1.5.0.  Here's what I have

```
writer = conn.create_batch_writer("my_table")
mut = Mutation("1234")
mut.put(cf="", cq="", cv="", is_delete=True)
writer.add_mutation(mut)
writer.close()
for r in conn.scan("my_table", scanrange=Range(srow="1234", erow="1234"), iterators=[RowDeletingIterator()]):
    print(r)
conn.close()
```

I'm printing the record to verify that the scanner is scanning the appropriate records. Sadly they don't appear to be getting deleted.  I'd appreciate any insight as Pyaccumulo's docs aren't the best.

I'm aware that there's a bug ([ACCUMULO-1800](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ACCUMULO-1800)) that requires one to use timestamps when deleting over Thrift, but when I specify a ts field, I just see a blank record in addition to the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Pyaccumulo, but I can tell you that the RowDeletingIterator doesn't use normal deletion entries.  It just uses a key with empty column family, qualifier and visibility and a value of DEL_ROW to indicate that an entire row should be deleted.  I would try not setting is_delete=True and giving the entry a value of DEL_ROW and see if that does what you want.

Comment: Setting a value of `DEL_ROW` doesn't seem to work, I just wind up with a record with cf=row_id and val=DEL_ROW.

Comment: Do you mean that the column family of the resulting entry is the row id you set in the mutation?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a delete_rows method in pyaccumulo.

```
def delete_rows(self, table, srow, erow):
    self.client.deleteRows(self.login, table, srow, erow)
```

You can use it like this:

```
conn.delete_rows(table, srow, erow)
```